# How to get the road traffic data of India?

Tags: data-request, government, traffic, india, openstreetmap

I need the traffic data for India location/area wise to perform some analysis.

Comment: is waze available in India?

Comment: Does that mean *cars* or also trucks, buses, scooters etc.? And what about the time distribution? What location indicators? Roads or areas? What about geographic distribution (granularity)? Please [edit] your question so that it is precise. Add an *india* tag, remove irrelevant *openstreetmap* and *goverment* tags. Why a *maps* tag?

Comment: @albert yes waze is avaialable in India

Comment: @JanDoggen yes, traffic includes all the vehicles and maybe OpenStreetMap or some API's might work hence including them here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question. All required information must be in there - comments can disappear. You also have not answered all my questions. Please take some time to write a *good* question. If the readers don't know what you want, they can't help you.

Comment: @AmanTandon well then there's your data...if its truly open/how to go about accessing it...is another story.

Comment: I am working on a project and i need a similar dataset.
Did you find the dataset?
If yes then where did you find it?

Comment: a newer answer may be useful for you: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/17430/1511 if not, please edit and we can re-open