# Data on road traffic in Germany

Tags: germany, traffic

I'm looking for **road traffic data** (e.g. average road traffic by day) **or congestion data** for German cities or other spatial units (e.g. a certain road or highway).  What would be important to me is, that there is some differentiation by time and spatial units (e.g. by day, week, month in city x or at road y). I'm not interested in highly aggregated figures such as annual averages. Ideally, I would look for (more or less live) data from traffic counts at some fixed points over time.

I know that there are automated counting stations [operated by BASt](https://www.bast.de/BASt_2017/DE/Verkehrstechnik/Fachthemen/v2-verkehrszaehlung/zaehl_node.html), but I can only find data up to 2018 (and in not very useful format). There is also [hourly information by road](https://www.bast.de/BASt_2017/DE/Verkehrstechnik/Fachthemen/v2-verkehrszaehlung/Stundenwerte.html?nn=1819490), but again only until 2018 as of today.

There also is an [old question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10167/traffic-statistics-by-roads-or-parts-of-any-german-city) in the forum (from 2016) with a similar topic, but the answer is outdated.

Can anyone point me to some resources?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the traffic data unofficially from TomTom, both "average" and "live" for any city (?) by using the API endpoint found in the Developer Tools --> Network.

https://api.midway.tomtom.com/ranking/live/CHE%2FCircle%2Fzurich

[image]

The list of cities can probably be scraped from this JS file:  https://tomtom.com/en_gb/traffic-index/commons-bf384d0d7ca7a781fbd8.js

because this URL is likely to change when they rebuild the site, here is an archive:
https://web.archive.org/web/2020032215

[image]

([my tweet thread](https://twitter.com/philshem/status/1241739025624567813))

Comment: Interesting, is this free? I worked with Google in the past and it is rather costly.

Answer (score 1):

Look at https://mcloud.de/, which is the open data portal of the German Ministry of Traffic and Infrastructure. They have links to various datasets from various areas of interest, including traffic.